# Override class methods to check for emptyness

Tags: python

I want to represent objects that can be None, a list, or a dict, so I create a class for this, e.g.,

```
class C(object):
    def __init__(self,c):
         self.content = c
```

Now what `__method__` can I override to check if the a C object o is None or empty, so that I can do something such as if o: do something, e.g.,

```
c1 = C(None)
c2 = C([])
c3 = C([1])
'1'if c1 else '0'
'1'  #I want this to be '0'
sage: '1'if c2 else '0'
'1'  # I want this to be '0'
sage: '1'if c3 else '0'
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try defining `__nonzero__`.

```
class C(object):
    def __init__(self,c):
         self.content = c
    def __nonzero__(self):
        return bool(self.content)

c1 = C(None)
c2 = C([])
c3 = C([1])
print 1 if c1 else 0 #result: 0
print 1 if c2 else 0 #result: 0
print 1 if c3 else 0 #result: 1
```

Comment: Or `__bool__` in Python 3+

Answer (score 1):

In Python 3:

```
class C(object):
    def __init__(self,c):
         self.content = c
    def __bool__(self):
        return bool(self.content)
c1 = C(None)
c1 = C(None)
c2 = C([])
c3 = C([1])
print('1'if c1 else '0')
print('1'if c2 else '0')
print('1'if c3 else '0')
```

prints:

```
0  
0
1
```

Python 2 and 3

```
class C(object):
    def __init__(self,c):
         self.content = c
    def __bool__(self):
        return bool(self.content)
    __nonzero__ = __bool__
```

Comment: Thanks, I use Python 2, but I like your suggestion that makes the code compatible with both versions